# How to get memory (RAM/ROM) consumption details in Android?

Tags: android, android-source, custom-rom

I am developing an Android App, where I have to display RAM consumption by each app running on the device as a foreground and background, I have gone through multiple solutions, but they only talk about total RAM and available RAM,
So my queries are

- Is there any public API available? I didn't find much in the Android
  Official document.
- Is it possible through System APP then how?
- Is there any private API available in the framework? I can modify my framework as well, but don't know where.

Comment: On older Android devices you could list all processes and as far as I remember also their memory usage. On modern Android devices getting the list of processes is disabled, you only see your own app process(es).

Answer (score 0):

[ActivityManager.getProcessMemoryInfo (int[] pids)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getProcessMemoryInfo(int%5B%5D)) is public API. However,

> As of Android Q, for regular apps this method will only return information about the memory info for the processes running as the caller's uid; no other process memory info is available and will be zero.

You can see `Settings -> System -> Developer Options (You need to enable the Developer Options) -> Memory -> Memory used by apps` how to do this.

[Settings](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/applications/ProcessStatsDetail.java) app uses `com.android.internal.app.procstats.ProcessStats`, `ActivityManager.getProcessMemoryInfo` uses `ProcessStats` to implement.